# suspended task with anonymous initiator

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have an issue with sharepoint 2013. some tasks return this error

> RequestorId: bfed8084-d7ed-de20-0000-000000000000. Details:
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionConfigurationFailedException
>   ---> System.ArgumentException: The value supplied was not valid runtime state. Parameter name: deserializedRuntimeState at
>   System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.Initialize(Object
>   deserializedRuntimeState, DynamicUpdateMap updateMap) at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowSession.ConfigureEnvironment(Activity
>   workflowDefinition, IWorkflowConfiguration workflowConfiguration,
>   IEnumerable`1 hostExtensions) at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ConfigureWorkflowSessionEnvironment(MessageSessionContext
>   messageSession, WorkflowSession workflowSession, Activity
>   rootActivity, IWorkflowConfiguration workflowConfiguration) --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ConfigureWorkflowSessionEnvironment(MessageSessionContext
>   messageSession, WorkflowSession workflowSession, Activity
>   rootActivity, IWorkflowConfiguration workflowConfiguration) at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ConfigureSession(WorkflowSessionResumptionContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.GotResumptionContextForProcessWaiter(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion
>   callback, IAsyncResult result)

[image]

Comment: did you enable "Anonymous Access" for this list/library which triggered the workflow? You said this issue occurs on some tasks, could you compare the differences between working tasks and problematic tasks? Also, please log in to your site using a site owner and add/edit an item to trigger the workflow again, compare the result.

Comment: no i didn't enable "anonymous acces" and i create this item myself. i don't have this issue with the whole list just three or four items